# How can you implement jquery stack for draggable ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why does the following not work... if I remove the stack option, the divs are draggable but they do not stack properly...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({ stack: ".draggable_div" });
});
```

Any ideas?... ps. the sample code on the jquery site also doesn't work... although there example does work...
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack

I have tried the following and this works.. but i don't know why?... if someone could explain that would be great...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({ stack: { group: "*", min: 50 } });
});
```

Kind regards J

Comment: what happens if you specify class with a dot like ".draggable_div"?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've updated my question, becuase I actually had the . but like an idiot i hadn't put it in the question!... I have also added a new part to the question... regards J

Comment: The value for 'stack' you have makes little sense unless the documentation is out of date, it clearly says it only accepts a selector, not an object.

Comment: Thanks Greg, but doing it as the docs state isn't working for me, but the following is: $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({ stack: { group: "*", min: 50 } }); ... weird... Regards J

Answer (score 1):

`stack` is a *selector*, and `"draggable_div"` is not a valid selector (unless you have a `<draggable_div>` in your XML).

Try adding a `.` before it:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({ stack: ".draggable_div" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've updated my question, becuase I actually had the . but like an idiot i hadn't put it in the question!... I have also added a new part to the question... regards J

Answer (score 0):

You should use a valid selector for `stack`

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({ stack: ".draggable_div" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've updated my question, becuase I actually had the . but like an idiot i hadn't put it in the question!... I have also added a new part to the question... regards J